# Calling a class function outside of the function it was declared

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a class function *player.Decide()* in another function where it wasn't declared. Im getting the error 'player is not defined. How would I go about fixing this?

```
def BattleLogic():
    global enemy, enemy_race, name, level, strength, dexterity, cunning, enemy_speed, player_speed, type_speed
    global move, turn, prefix
    if enemy in ['deer']:
        enemy_race = 'animal'
    if enemy_race == 'animal':
        chance = random.randint(1,1000)
        if chance <= 10:
            prefix = 'crippled'
        elif chance > 10 and chance <= 50:
            prefix = 'old'
        elif chance >50 and chance <= 250:
            prefix = 'young'
        elif chance > 250 and chance <= 750:
            prefix = None
        elif chance > 750 and chance <= 950:
            prefix = 'strong'
        elif chance > 950 and chance <= 990:
            prefix = 'alpha'
        elif chance > 990 and chance <= 999:
            prefix = 'possessed'
        elif chance == 1000:
            prefix = '*CONVERTED*'
        else:
            prefix = 'error'
        opponent = Enemy(str(prefix),str(enemy),str(enemy_race))

    player = Player(str(name),level,strength,dexterity,cunning)
    player.Initiative()
    opponent.Initiative()
    if enemy_speed > player_speed:
        move = 0
    elif player_speed > enemy_speed:
        move = 1
    else:
        move = random.randint(0,1)
    turn = 0
    Battle()

def Battle():
    global turn, move, prefix, enemy, type_speed, enemy_title
    if turn == 0:
        print('\n\n')
        if prefix == None:
            enemy_title = enemy.capitalize()
        else:
            enemy_title = prefix.capitalize()+' '+enemy.capitalize()
        SlowPrint('A '+enemy_title+' gets into position for battle',type_speed,0.5)
        if move == 1:
            SlowPrint(enemy_title+' makes the first move',type_speed,0.25)
        else:
            SlowPrint('You make the first move',type_speed,0.25)
    if move == 0:
        turn += 1
        move = 1
        player.Decide()
    else:
        turn += 1
        move = 0
        opponent.Decide()
```

Comment: You should include all your code, including the `Enemy` and  `Player` definitions. Assuming the issue is because you are trying to call the `Player.Decide()` method but with an `Enemy` object. You should take a read through some object oriented programming guides to see why this doesn't work. For example: https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a player object into the function. The you are free to use player.Decide().

The major problems with your coding, which is my personal opinion, is that you do not have the habit of passing something into the function, which as a result forces you to declare too many global variables.

A simple example (in your case, you want the object to be a player)

```
def Battle(obj):
    return obj.Decide()
```

Comment: ohhhh, I see. so I simply place the object in the function parameter?? and yes I get where you're coming from with global variable usage, Ive always been told that. but Ive taught myself this way and its just how I think now, I havent encountered any problems yet :) im sure eventually... but change is hard. thanks so much though :)

Comment: To expand on what @caden said, you will often have  a set of variables that belong together.  To avoid having to pass all of those variables individually in all of your calls, you can put them all in a class and then just pass an instance of that class into your methods. - you can put them in a dict and do the same thing.  you can also define them as instance variables, and then all of the methods in a particular instance of your class will have implicit access to those variables.

Comment: @Louis Chadfield Yes, it is a good practice to put objects/parameters that you may need in the function into the ().

Comment: anything but globals.  globals are very seldom the right thing.  They are mostly used for constants.  Just about anything else should be passed between functions/methods.  It is especially rare for the 'global' keyword to be the right thing.  If you're modifying a global inside a function, there's usually a better way.  I program in Python all the time, and I can't remember the last time I chose to use the 'global' keyword.